# Ruby: ElasticSearch + Tire error Tire::Search::SearchRequestFailed - IndexMissingException?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, elasticsearch, tire

I want to use ElasticSearch + Tire to search stored in MongoDB.

However, I'm getting the following error when I try to perform a search:

**Tire::Search::SearchRequestFailed in SearchController#index**

```
404 : {"error":"IndexMissingException[[events] missing]","status":404}
```

From what I understand, this tells me that the indexes are missing for the Event, even though I've told it to generate them when I ran `db:setup`.

Model:

```
class Event
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps 

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  field :name, :type => String
  field :description, :type => String
  field :started_at => Time
  field :ended_at => Time

  def to_indexed_json
    self.as_json
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
  def search
    Event.tire.search(params[:q])
  end
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this please?

Comment: Please update the model -- I don't see any `field` definitions there. All in all, when you load the app, the should be created, unless it already exists.

Comment: @karmi: I've added fields to the model now.

Comment: I've realized that the issue was that the model was not getting added to the ElasticSearch index when it was saved. I've tried manually adding / importing it, but I can't seem to get it to work… Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

... or even better, just run :

```
rake environment tire:import CLASS=Event FORCE=true
```

Answer (score 3):

Set an Initializer ( the following will work locally on your machine and on heroku with bonsai add-on too, just in case ... ):

```
# config/initializers/bonsai.rb

if ENV['BONSAI_INDEX_URL']
  Tire.configure do
    url "http://index.bonsai.io"
  end
  BONSAI_INDEX_NAME = ENV['BONSAI_INDEX_URL'][/[^\/]+$/]
else
  app_name = Rails.application.class.parent_name.underscore.dasherize
  BONSAI_INDEX_NAME = "#{app_name}-#{Rails.env}"
end
```

In your model add the `index_name` :

```
class Event
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps 

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  index_name BONSAI_INDEX_NAME

  field :name, :type => String
  field :description, :type => String
  field :started_at => Time
  field :ended_at => Time

  def to_indexed_json
    self.as_json
  end
end
```

Then open your Rails console with `rails c` and run :

```
1.9.2p290 :001 >Event.create_elasticsearch_index
 => 200 : {"ok":true,"acknowledged":true} 
1.9.2p290 :002 > Tire.index BONSAI_INDEX_NAME
1.9.2p290 :003 >        import Event.all
1.9.2p290 :004?>   refresh
1.9.2p290 :005?> end
```

You should see something similar :

```
MONGODB (0ms) ... ['system.namespaces'].find({})
MONGODB (0ms) ... ['events'].find({})
 => #<Tire::Index:0xca8fb18 @name="your-app-name-development",@response=200 : {"ok":true,"_shards":{"total":10,"successful":5,"failed":0}}> 
1.9.2p290 :006 >
```

Now start rails and re-try.

Comment: For posterity, the `index_name` stuff shouldn't really be necessary anymore with Bonsai. We loosened up our earlier one-index-per-addon design in order to play nicely with Tire's conventions with index naming and usage.

Answer (score 1):

... see also :

```
Event.index.import Event.all
```

This way all your records are loaded into memory, serialized into JSON, and sent down the wire to ElasticSearch. This, as well as the two solutions before, should evoid "IndexMissingException[[events] missing]" error.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you modify the configuration. Try removing the Tire.configure if you define one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you indexed your Event model ?  And your Venues model ?  Elastic search is also looking for the Venues index

I have a rake task to reindex my Models

> desc "Reindex event"
>   task :reindex_events => :environment do
>
> ```
> batch_size = 1000
> count = batch_size
>
> Event.all.find_in_batches(:batch_size => batch_size) { |objects|
>
>   puts "Count: " + count.to_s
>   count += batch_size
>
>   Event.index.import objects
> }
> ```
>
> end

Comment: Interesting, does the bundled import Rake tasks comes short?

Comment: @Andrew: Sorry, I copied the wrong error message, as I was also trying to test it with my Venue model as well; it should've said `[[events] missing]`. I've updated the question above to reflect this.

Comment: I've tried `rake db:mongoid:create_indexes` and `rake environment tire:import CLASS='Event'`, but I can't seem to get it to work, which is very frustrating. Any help would be greatly appreciated.